# SpriteKit: How to create a region that's the same size as the device screen?

Tags: sprite-kit

I'm working in SpriteKit and I need to create a 'playable area', an area that is same size as the device screen so that I can stop my player from moving off-screen.

I'm using the following line of code:

```
var playableRect: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
```

But the resulting rectangle is about a quarter of the device screen, with a corner of that rectangle at what looks to be the center of the screen. And the device orientation doesn't change that.

I've tried everything I can think of. Nothing is working.

How do I create a rectangle that's the same size as the device screen?

Here's my full coding, after changing to include Gene's suggestion. I incorporated Gene's suggestion by revising playableRect inside the didMove method. But the result is unchanged with that coding.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import CoreMotion

@objcMembers
class GameSceneUsingTilt: SKScene {
  
  let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "player-motorbike")
  let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
  
  var playableRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
  
  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    
    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "road")
    background.zPosition = -1
    addChild(background)
    
    if let particles = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Mud") {
      let farRightPt = frame.maxX // start the emitter at the far right x-point of the view
      particles.advanceSimulationTime(10)
      particles.position.x = farRightPt
      addChild(particles)
    }
    
    let nearLeftPt = frame.minX * 3 / 4 // start the player at a quarter of the way to the far left x-point of the view
    
    player.position.x = nearLeftPt
    
    player.zPosition = 1
    
    addChild(player)
    
    motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
    
    // coding below shows outline of playableRect
    
          let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
          let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
          // let size = CGSize(width: bounds.size.width * scale, height: bounds.size.height * scale)
    
    playableRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.size.width * scale, height: bounds.size.height * scale)
    
    
    drawPlayableRect(rect: playableRect)
    
  }
  
  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    
  }
  
  override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    
  }
  
  override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    
  }
  
  func boundsCheck() {
    
    let playableRect = CGRect(x: frame.minX, y: frame.minY, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
    
    let bottomLeft = CGPoint(x: playableRect.minX, y: playableRect.minY)
    let topRight = CGPoint(x: playableRect.maxX, y: playableRect.maxY)
    
    if player.position.x <= bottomLeft.x {
      player.position.x = bottomLeft.x
    }
    
    if player.position.x >= topRight.x {
      player.position.x = topRight.x
    }
    
    if player.position.y <= bottomLeft.y {
      player.position.y = bottomLeft.y
    }
    
    if player.position.y >= topRight.y {
      player.position.y = topRight.y
    }
    
  }
  
  override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    
    if let accelerometerData = motionManager.accelerometerData {
      
      // note that since the game will be running in landscape mode, up and down movement is controlled by the x axis and right to left movement is controlled by the y-axis...so this is the inverse of what you'd normally think.
      
      let changeX = CGFloat(accelerometerData.acceleration.y) * 4
      let changeY = CGFloat(accelerometerData.acceleration.x) * 4
      
      // you have to subtract from x position and add to the y position because device is rotated so the axises aren't what you would normally expect.
      
      player.position.x -= changeX
      player.position.y += changeY
      
      // check to make sure position isn't outside payable area:
      
      boundsCheck()
      
    }  
    
  }
  
  // function below shows outline of playableRect
  
  func drawPlayableRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let shape = SKShapeNode()
    let path = CGMutablePath()
    path.addRect(rect)
    shape.path = path
    shape.strokeColor = .red
    shape.lineWidth = 4.0
    addChild(shape)
  }

}
```

Comment: This seems like an issue with screen size in pixels and screen resolution. How are you using playableRect? Which method are you passing it to?

Comment: Thanks for the response. At the moment, I'm just using it in didMove(to method where I put a border around it to see where it is on the device screen. But eventually I'll be using it in the update method.

Comment: Maybe you've got things set up so that the rectangle you're seeing is centered at a corner and you're only seeing 1/4 of it?

Comment: Thanks for the thought. I don't see how. It's pretty basic programming. I can't find a way to add coding to this comment, so I've edited the original question to show my coding. I've added Gene's suggestion by revising the size of the playableRect in didMove but adding that coding doesn't change the size and position of the rectangle ...it still looks the same as it did w/o that revision.

Answer (score 0):

Use: UIScreen.main.nativeBounds

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. The rectangle is still about a quarter of the device screen, with a corner in the center of the screen.

Comment: I've rebuild your project! Indeed I had the same issue. You have to set a "LAUNCH SCREEN FILE" in the App Settings! Look at the picture: http://www.mdobler.com/001.png.

Comment: Hi and thank you so much for the comment. I've never worked with that particular setting! Unfortunately, when I set the Launch Screen File to "Main", I still have the same problem. Did that fix it for you?

Comment: Yes it did! http://www.mdobler.com/test.zip here is my project.

Comment: Hey, that works! Thank you so, so much! I'm going to have to figure out what I did wrong in my programming! Thank you again!